# How to add custom properties to a Spring Batch Step, Job, Flow?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I would like to associate custom (read-only) metadata to Spring Batch jobs, flows, steps. (This is not same as storing arbitrary data to execution context, at the step execution level!). It would have been nice, if I could do something like this:

```
@Bean
public Step<MyMetadata> sampleStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    MyMetadata myMetaData  = ...;
    return new StepBuilder<M>("mySampleStep", jobRepository)
                .withCustomMetadata(myMetaData);
                .<String, String>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
}
```

.. so that later, I can get back my custom metadata (say I want to build UI console to visualize jobs, steps, flows):

```
...
SimpleJob simpleJob = ...;
Step<MyMetadata> myStep = (Step<MyMetadata>)simpleJob.getStep("myStep")
MyMetadata myMetadata = myStep.getCustomMetadata();
```

Unfortunately, Spring Batch API provides a maze of builders creating concrete classes with no way to extend jobs, steps or flows in the above manner. Nothing in the Spring Batch documentations shows this is even possible.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: I have considered 3 workarounds:

1. Copy/paste/re-write some builders from Spring Batch sources. Not great.

2. Have a separate "factory" step bean that can create steps. Works, but clumsy.

3. Have a completely separate metadata storage. Too much effort...

Comment: I would be curious to have a practical example of this kind of metadata and how it can be used later by a client (from an API point of view). Anyway, I added an answer, which is not a workaround.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine imagine that I need to have a web dashboard of jobs that I can launch, or I need to pick out certain steps to rerun, know what parameters to supply (e.g. web inout form),  .. or have "reverse" functionality, when one can run "undo " steps to repair bad data. These all requires extra metadata to know the capabilities and structure of job and steps. Note that such metadata is immutable, it would be a waste to persist through the job execution context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You can extend the job/step provided by Spring Batch (along with their respective builders if you want to use builders) and add that.

Comment: Thanks, at this point I too realized this is not possible...  but I have a workaround. This seems to be a serious design flow of the Spring Batch API - developers should be able to associate (immutable) custom metadata directly and the API should allow it. What you suggest works, but is very cumbersome, especially because of all the "builders" ... I marked you answer as correct nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would like to do some work before step/job and after step/job. Did you consider to use StepExecutionListener or JobExecutionListener? Those listeners allow to do some work after and berofe job. For instance you can store some data in db, or cache, or executionContext(step/job level). If I understand your needs rightly.

Comment: As I mentioned, I do not want to store such metadata, as it is not bound to a particular (job/step) execution, but the job/step itself and does not change between runs. I want to code it, not store it.